# How to distinguish between views in a ListFragment with CustomArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I would like to know if I can add logic\distinguish between views in my onListItemClick ?
I have a listFragment with several views in it and would like to perform different operations.  I have attempted to use the .isPressed() Method on my views with no success.

What is the correct way to do this.  -Thank You.

---

Per the Advice of the marked answer I implemented the code below in my CustomArrayAdapter and all is working well.  I have a ListFragment that implements onListItemClick for the cell AND clickable imagesViews within the same cell. Hope this helps the next person.

```
public class ZAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>{

protected static final String TAG = "myLog";
Context context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> myListOfMaps;

public ZAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myListOfMaps) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, myListOfMaps);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=context;

    this.myListOfMaps = myListOfMaps;

}


public class MyViewHolder
{

    ImageView editImage;
    TextView tvTitle;
    TextView tvSubTitle;
    TextView tvRepEmail;
    TextView tvRepCell;

    public MyViewHolder(View v)
    {
        editImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
         tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
         tvSubTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_subTitle);
         tvRepEmail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvRepEmail);
         tvRepCell = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvRepCell);
    }


}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final int index=position;

    View row = convertView;
    MyViewHolder holder = null;


    if(row==null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    holder = new MyViewHolder(row);


    row.setTag(holder);

    }else{

        holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();



    }



    holder.editImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.edit_img);holder.editImage.setTag("goEdit");
    holder.tvTitle.setText(myListOfMaps.get(position).get("prod"));
    holder.tvSubTitle.setText(myListOfMaps.get(position).get("dist"));
    holder.tvRepEmail.setText(myListOfMaps.get(position).get("repEmail"));
    holder.tvRepCell.setText(myListOfMaps.get(position).get("repPhone"));

    holder.editImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "*****************  getView() *********called"+index);

        }
    });


    return row;
}
```

}

-Thank You

Comment: the click listeners should be in the adapter not in the ListItemClick listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you can handle it in onListItemClick function. One place you can handle event clicks is in Adapter class - getView function. In this function, you can find your controls and register event handlers.

Note that, you only set event handlers in this block

```
if (convertView == null) {

    // Find your controls and register event handlers here  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Let me give it a try brb.

Comment: I took your advice and all worked out well.  I have posted the Answer in the original post for the next person. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Best place to set click listeners on each view in a row is your `ViewHolder`. in view holder constructor, set `onClickListener` for child views that you want to set. Also if you need to know the `id` of the row you should define an `id'` field in you `ViewHolder` class and then make use of it in you `onClickListener`. Don't forget to update the viewholder id in getView method (or if you are using `CursorAdapter` in `bindView`).

Answer (score 0):

The `View` parameter in your `onListItemClick` method is the view that was clicked. In your case it is `v`. To take the appropriate action, just identify what view it is by getting its id and delegating as appropriate.

Here is one possible structure:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.row_icon:
            // do something
        case R.id.row_title:
            // do something
        case R.id.row_subTitle:
            // do something
    }
}
```